# Check value of variable to skip task in Ant

Tags: ant, build

I have the following `target` in my build file:

```
<target name="copyLibrary">
    <copy toDir="${workingDir}/${location}" includeEmptyDirs="false">
        <fileset dir="${librariesRoot}/${libraryDir}" includes="*"/>
    </copy>
</target>
```

What I want to do is check the value of `${libraryDir}` and if it is a particular directory, do not perform the copy.

I have tried to change the `fileset` to use nested `include` and `exclude` tags but it doesn't like this.  I have also tried to add an `unless` attribute to the target and copy, but these are not allowed.  I am currently working on the `if` attribute on the target to see where I get.  I have a feeling that I will probably need to change from a `fileset` to something like a `dirset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<fileset>` can have nested `<include>` and `<exclude>` elements. These `<include>` and `<exclude>` elements can have `if` and `unless` attributes.

In your case, an `<include>` with an `unless` may work:

```
<condition property="libraryDir-is-scorned">
    <equals arg1="${libraryDir}" arg2="unlovedLibrary"/>
</condition>

<copy toDir="${workingDir}/${location}" includeEmptyDirs="false">
    <fileset dir="${librariesRoot}/${libraryDir}">
        <include name="*" unless="libraryDir-is-scorned"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: This looks just the ticket!  Thanks for your answer!